# Wordpress: fit for per-region website? Another better CMS?

Tags: wordpress, web, content-management-system, multilingual

I'm looking to help a friend who needs a website for his project. I know wordpress a little, but there might be better options.

The needs are:
- have a splash screen prompting for region (like [this site](http://www.nsk-dental.com/))
- have some pages available only for a given region.
- allow the non-it guy to update the contents.

Wordpress is the only one I know as web design isn't my specialty. I'd have gone for a template like [Avada](https://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226), but again, better leads are more than welcome.

Thanks in advance for your inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the downvote really helped me and certainly will help other users as there's no comment whatsoever explaining why this post is bad. Don't give leads or guidance by the way.

So, whatever. I found a solution to this. The following plugin works like a charm:
https://www.fla-shop.com/products/wp-plugins/world/continents/

A simple purchase gives total control and removes the watermark. The best part regarding my need was the capability to write custom callback code as explained in this article.
https://www.fla-shop.com/blog/adding-custom-javascript-to-the-map/

[image]